# find largest value on nested for loop for every element of the outer loop

Tags: python

Given two lists , I'm calculating a distance between words in a nested for loop:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

l = ['mango','apple']
l2 = ['ola','john']

for i in l:
    for j in l2:
        print(i,j,fuzz.ratio(i,j))


mango ola 25
mango john 22
apple ola 25
apple john 0
```

I would like to find the maximum value for every element of the outer loop. Result would be:

```
mango ola 25
apple ola 25
```

Since the other elements have a lower value.

One strategy that I could think of is to use pandas, but I was thinking rather of a pure python implementation. Pandas way for reference:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd

l = ['mango','apple']
l2 = ['ola','johnkoo']

result = []
for i in l:
    for j in l2:
        result.append((i,j,fuzz.ratio(i,j)))

df = pd.DataFrame(result,columns = ['word1','word2','distance'])

idx = df.groupby(['word1'])['distance'].transform(max) == df['distance']
print(df[idx])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max) function allows to select a criterium to sort values (therefore specifying what should be considered *maximum*) using the keyword argument `key`. So, you can sort by the third item of each `(i,j,fuzz.ratio(i,j))` generated in the inner loop:

```
for i in l:
    print(max([(i,j,fuzz.ratio(i,j)) for j in l2], key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

Outputs

```
('mango', 'ola', 25)
('apple', 'ola', 25)
```

To format it as in your example: `print(' '.join(max([(i,j,str(fuzz.ratio(i,j))) for j in l2], key=lambda x: x[2])))`.